# Jfrog Artifactory what is used for

Tags: repository, artifactory

I've a question about Jfrog Artifactory.
I don't know for what it is used. Can you explain me this in practical way ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

From the tag description of [artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory/info):

> Artifactory is a binary repository manager for use by build tools (like Maven and Gradle), dependency management tools (like Ivy, NuGet and RubyGems) and build servers (like Jenkins, TeamCity and Bamboo). It comes as downloadable version (OSS, Pro and Enterprise with additional features) and cloud SaaS version.

Simply put it's a self-hosted/on-premise remote location in which you can store Java/Maven dependencies (with the open source version) and various other package types (NPM, rubygems etc) with the pro version

Comment: So I can understand it like this -> I put there dependencies which will be always accessible for me ?
Sth like a local repository ?

Comment: To a degree yes: you can put artifacts/dependencies there to share them across machines, share them with other devs/teams etc. It is all accessible through web endpoints, and can be configured as your remote repository in gradle/maven.